# Create a program that outputs the times in which the values in another list satisfies a condtion

Tags: python, list

So for example say I have a list of times (0,1,2,3,4,5) in seconds, and I have another list of speeds at those times (0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5) in m/s.

How would I write a program that can tell me which speeds in the second list cross a threshold of 1 m/s and also the times at which those speeds were measured.

the output would look something like :

speeds that cross threshold: [1.5,2,2.5]

times that speed cross threshold: [3,4,5]

so far I've managed to create the first part using this code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii8tF.png

I'm not sure how to get the specific times based on when those speeds are greater than the threshold.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do not post images of code. Copy the code instead in a [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code block.

Comment: Instead of iterating through the elements in `speed_list` you could iterate over it's lenght. So, once you find an index for which `speed_list`, you have the index that correspond to that item in `time_list`.

Comment: Your function takes an argument `resp_list`, but never uses it. Maybe you mean `speed_list`?

Comment: Do you need to worry about the speeds crossing the threshold from above? In other words, can you slow down? Also, why do you count `2` as crossing the threshold, but not `1`?

Comment: @Mark based on the examples and the code, I think by "crossing the threshold" the OP means "strictly greater than".

Comment: Okay @IgnatiusReilly maybe I'm just misreading. Why then is `2` in the list of threshold crossings?

Comment: OTH: I'm reading this as crossing multiples of `1  m/s` for example: crossing `1` then crossing `2`, maybe I've over complicated it.

Answer (score 1):

You could pair each time of measure with it's speed and then return a list with only the time values such that their speed is greater than the threshold.

```
time_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
speed_list = [0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5]

def find_times(times, speeds, threshold):
    timexspeed = list(zip(times, speeds))
    return [time for time, speed in timexspeed if speed > threshold]

find_times(time_list, speed_list, 1)
>>>[3, 4, 5]
```

Alternative, as I suggested in comments, you can use a strategy based on iterating through the length of the list instead of it's elements:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] <some_condition>:
        <do_domething_with> list2[i]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time'] = (0,1,2,3,4,5)
df['speed'] = (0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5)

cutoff = 1
df[df.speed >= cutoff].time
```